# Show that $T$ is an isomorphism of X in a closed subspace of $Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $T \in B(X,Y)=\{T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y) | T$ is bounded $\}$ with  $X$ and $Y$ Banach space such that it exist $\delta >0$ , $\|Tx\| \geq \delta \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$. Show that $T$ is an isomorphism of X in a closed subspace of $Y$

---

I need some help to solve this. I dont know where to begin with.

What I know about isomorphism

1. maybe find T $\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ Bijectif with $\|T\|=\|x\|$
2. $T:X \rightarrow Y$ isomorphe iff Ker T=0 and ImT=Y
3. $X \rightarrow X^*$ is isomorphic if X is an Hilberspace

What else I know is since T is bounded then T is continuous $\implies$ kerT is closed.

Comment: I think you mean $\|Tx\|\geq \delta \|x\|$. $\|Tx\|\leq \delta \|x\|$ follows directly from $T$ being bounded. Besides, what is your definition of 'isomorphism between normed spaces'?

Comment: Ok I have correct my little mistake. 1 , 2 ,3 is all I know about isomophism ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $Tx = Ty$. Then
$$ 0 = \Vert Tx-Ty \Vert \geq \delta \Vert x - y \Vert \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Vert x-y \Vert \leq 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \Vert x - y \Vert = 0, $$
which is possible if and only if $x = y$. Hence $T$ is injective.

Suppose now that $(Tx_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset R_T$ is a convergent sequence in the range of $R_T$.
Then it is in particular Cauchy, i.e.
$$ \Vert Tx_n - Tx_m \Vert \to 0 , \quad n,m \to \infty. $$
Then
$$ \Vert x_n-x_m \Vert \leq \frac{1}{\delta} \Vert Tx_n-Tx_m \Vert \to 0, \quad n,m\to\infty, $$
so that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \subset X$ is Cauchy. Since $X$ is a Banach space, this sequence converges to some $x\in X$. Then by the boundedness of $T$,
$$ Tx_n \to Tx \in R_T, \quad n \to \infty. $$
Hence, the range of $T$ is closed.

Thus $T:X\to R_T$ is an isomorphism between $X$ and the closed subspace $R_T$ of $Y$.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand why the range of T is closed

Comment: @seito We proved that the limit of an arbitrary convergent sequence in $R_T$ belongs to $R_T$, implying closedness.